# Webscraping with Rvest in freedom24 page

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I´m triying to do web scraping in this web --> https://es.freedom24.com/ipo/all

I want to get the information of the IPOs. If I select the website and copy it, I get this:

```
Braze, Inc.
Crecimiento del precio en la apertura
34.15 %
FECHA DE SALIDA A LA BOLSA

16.11.2021
PRECIO DE COLOCACIÓN

$65.00
PRECIO DE APERTURA

$87.20
FINAL DEL BLOQUEO
17.02.2022
Leer más
```

This is similar what I want to get using webscraping with Rvest. To do that, I use this code:

```
library(rvest)


url = "https://es.freedom24.com/ipo/all"

web <- read_html(url)

datos_web <- web %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="tm-f24eu-ipo-card-past-grid-item"]') %>%
  html_text()
```

But I get NULL (empty) data.

How can I do webscraping to get the information what I want?

Comment: Using `RSelenium` you can use `remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="pjax-container"]/section[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div[3]/div[2]') %>% 
  html_text()` to get all text of all the IPO's. But you further need to modify it to understand it.

Comment: but why is not possible with rvest? maybe need a delay until website load?

Comment: I am not able to access the website